# Input boxes not lining up correctly

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the rather vague title, I couldn't think up a better description for my problem.

I have a simple HTML form:

```
<html>
<FIELDSET>
    <DIV>
        <SPAN class="label">Label 1</SPAN>
        <DIV class="div">
            <input id="input1" value="The first input box">  
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
    </FIELDSET>    

    <FIELDSET>
        <DIV>
            <SPAN class="label">Label 2</SPAN>
            <INPUT id ="input2" class="textbox" value="the second input box">
        </DIV>
    </FIELDSET>
</html>
```

with some simple styling

```
.label{float:left}
.textbox{float:right;width:75%}
.div{float:right;width:75%}
```

With this, I would expect both input boxes to be left aligned, as input2 is has float:right with a width of 75%, and the parent div of input 1 is also floating right with the same width. However, thy don't line up correctly, and I am not sure why. Tested in IE8 and firefox 9 - jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/nrF2W/

Note: I tried to make the simplest possible example which still showed the problem I was having. The div containing the first input box is intended to have more than just a single input box.

Edit: Say for example the initial input div should be:

```
<DIV class="div">
    <input value="1">
    <input type="checkbox"> 
</DIV>
```

Which is an input box followed by a checkbox, on the same line. Setting the width of the input box to be 75% doesn't work for this situation. To clarify, its not the length of the input boxes not lining up that I have the issue with, it's their lack of alignment on the left.

Comment: Are they meant to be 2 totally, non-related inputs? If the inputs relate in any way they should probably be in the same fieldset.  Do you definitely want the, in separate fieldsets?

Comment: Yes, the inputs in each fieldset are supposed to be totally unrelated.

Comment: i just gone through your fiddle example, found that the `width:75%` for `div` does not match with the width of `div`  both `fieldset` changing width of your `.div` class to `76%` you can achieve this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nrF2W/2/

You had 75% for the div alone, not for the input

Comment: This works fine for a single input box within the div, but not if anything else is added. I've made an edit to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

change `.div{float:right;width:75%}` to `.div input{float:right;width:75%}`

Answer (score 0):

They don’t line up since you are setting properties on a `div` element on one hand and on an `input` element on the other. But even if you fix this, the design is not robust—check out what happens if the labels are long and/or the browser window is very narrow or very wide.

A more robust approach is to use a table, with labels in one column, input fields in another. Then the first column will automatically be as wide as needed, and you need not make arbitrary guesses like 75%.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/YE288/11/

it's not in div's any more - I prefer using lists for form elements. But it will line up depending on how wide you set your labels.

---

EDIT:
Using my example, you align the inputs to the size of the labels. This will create a uniform poition for any input - I'm not sure why you're insisting on using the extra div.